# subtract textboxes and put into another

Tags: c#, .net, textbox

I have a value in txtAtraso.Text and another in txtCorriente.Text on my WindowsForm and I want to subtract Corriente from Atraso and display it in another textbox called txtAtraso2.Text.

```
int a = int.Parse(txtAtraso.Text);
int b = int.Parse(txtCorriente.Text);

txtAtraso2.Text = (a - b).ToString();
```

It throws a Format Exception.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: it is not working, it throws a Format Exception.

Comment: @CristinaA - Then you should put that info into your post. It's a pretty important detail...

Comment: You have text that can't be parsed.  Do favor TryParse.

Comment: Then the input of the user is not a valid integer. Maybe it contains commas or similar.

Comment: @LarsTech I will try that, appreciate it.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the exact error its throwing it's in spanish and couldn't find the exact one in English but I will update it.

Comment: @CristinaA - Even if you run a Spanish error through Google Translate or something, as long as something about the error is added to your post, it'll improve your question. But the above comments are correct. At least one of those TextBoxes has something other than "pure" integer characters.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb i am very new as you can see to both coding and this website but appreciate your feedback and will work on asking complete questions.
have a good day

Answer (score 1):

You should use int.TryParse instead. Something like:

```
if(int.TryParse(txtAtraso.Text, out int a) && int.TryParse(txtCorriente.Text, out int b))
{
   txtAtraso2.Text = (a - b).ToString();
}
```

This way it'll check if txtAtraso.Text and txtCorriente.Text can be converted into integers first before subtracting.

Comment: You should make sure that the `Text` property is still set to something meaningful if one of the `TryParse` calls returns false.